# The difference between @(a==1) and @(posedge a)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In non-synthesizable code, what is the difference between:

```
@(a==1);
```

and

```
@(posedge a);
```

Are they actually behaving the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example ([on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5aw)) shows they are not the same :

```
module test;

  logic a = 1'b0;
  initial begin
    #100ns a <= 1'b1;
    #100ns a <= 1'b0;
    #100ns a <= 1'b1;
    #1000ns $finish;
  end

  initial begin
    @(a == 1'b1)
    $display("%t : a == 1    (1) %b",$realtime, a);
    @(a == 1'b1)
    $display("%t : a == 1    (2) %b",$realtime, a);
    @(a == 1'b1)
    $display("%t : a == 1    (3) %b",$realtime, a);
  end

  initial begin
    @(posedge a)
    $display("%t : posedge a (1)",$realtime);
    @(posedge a)
    $display("%t : posedge a (2)",$realtime);
    @(posedge a)
    $display("%t : posedge a (3)",$realtime);
  end

endmodule
```

Which displays

```
100 : posedge a (1)
100 : a == 1    (1) 1
200 : a == 1    (2) 0
300 : a == 1    (3) 1
300 : posedge a (2)
```

`@(posedge a)` unblocks on a true transition to 1 from x/z/0.
`@(a == 1)` unblocks when true on a change in a either before or after the change.

### bit ?

When a ideclared as bit it can only hold 0 or 1, 2-state not 4-state (0,1,x,z). Therefore posedge can only be a 0 -> 1 transition. In modelsim 10.1 it does not change the behaviour of the example. [AldoT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3534533/aldot) (OP) made the observation that `@(a==1)` now behaves the same as `@(a)`.

Comment: "bit" can only be 0 or 1. In this case, `@(a==1)` is equivalent to `@(a)` - provided a is 1-bit. The behavior may be different if a is more than one bit - I haven't tried this case.

Answer (score -2):

The first waits for `a` to be `1`

The second waits for `a` to transition from 0 to 1.

Comment: Well, @(posedge a) will trigger when transition from x/z to 1, at least in my simulator.

Comment: @Morgan, Yes I understand it is for transition from 0/x/z to 1. The thing is, either @(a==1) or @(posedge a) will trigger when transition from 0/x/z to 1. It looks like they are behaving the same way.

Comment: @AldoT: yes, they'll both trigger in that moment. But after that `@(posedge a)` will wait for another transition `0->1`, while `@(a==1)` will be active until you drive `a` with `0`.

Comment: @Qiu I guess that should be `wait(a==1)` that is active until we drive `a` to `0`.